# Transforming a string to list of integer then sum them up in haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

I have a function checkIfTrue where I want to computes a string and check if the sum of the string is true. Like for example, I have a String "ABC" where A= 1, B=2, C=3.Let say

input:

> checkIfTrue "ABC" 2

output:

> False

as the sum of A+B+C = 6.

```
checkIfTrue :: String -> Int -> Bool
checkIfTrue = sum x + xs .words 
    | x <- A = 1
    |x <- B = 2
    |x <- C = 3
```

This is what I had in mind but I don't know how to compare if the sum of the input is the same. Sorry if what I had in mind is ridiculous.

Comment: How are the values per character is set? You may need something like `Data.Map.fromList $ zip ['A'..'Z'] [1..]` to start with.

Comment: `(==) . sum . map (subtract (fromEnum 'A') . fromEnum)`

Comment: @karakfa This looks super cool. I just would like to to know the time complexity of `fromEnum  'A'`.

Comment: It should be constant time, I trust the compiler to do the right thing.

Comment: the snippet above maps A to 0.  Add one for your convention.

Comment: @karakfa, mind if I steal that and add it to my answer? I didn't include how to create that function and a one-liner is a lot nicer than pattern matching.

Comment: @jkeuhlen go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a function with signature

```
:: Char -> Int
```

Or more likely

```
:: Char -> Maybe Int
```

since only 3 values in the domain `Char` will have valid outputs. You can write this as:

```
charVal :: Char -> Maybe Int
charVal 'A' = Just 1
charVal 'B' = Just 2
charVal 'C' = Just 3
charVal _   = Nothing
```

Then you can `sum` over the `map` of the string, using `Data.Maybe`'s `catMaybes` to ignore the `Nothing` values. This can be generalized with `Data.Maybe`'s `mapMaybe :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [b]`

```
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)

charVal :: Char -> Maybe Int
charVal 'A' = Just 1
charVal 'B' = Just 2
charVal 'C' = Just 3
charVal _   = Nothing

checkIfTrue :: String -> Int -> Bool
checkIfTrue s k = k == stringSum where
  stringSum = sum . (mapMaybe charVal) $ s
```

Comment: You can also use `mapMaybe` instead of `catMaybes . map` to make it a little simpler.

Comment: @jkeuhlen thanks! I'm still learning Haskell myself and half the reason I answer questions on this tag is to learn about new stdlib functions to simplify my code. What's that old saying? The fastest way to get the right answer to a question is to answer it wrong and be corrected? :)

Comment: I do the same thing, but I'm a little further along with Haskell. `mapMaybe` has cleaned up a lot of my code along the way!

Answer (score 2):

`String` in Haskell is a type synonym for `[Char]`. You can utilize this to your advantage here!

Write a function that translates `Char -> Int`, then map that over your list:

```
stringValue :: String -> Int 
stringValue s = sum $ map charToInt s
```

Now you can use this function to write your `checkIfTrue` in a simpler manner:

```
checkIfTrue :: String -> Int -> Bool 
checkIfTrue s i = stringValue s == i
```

As @karakfa notes in the comments, you can write a simple `charToInt` function making use of the `Enum` typeclass that will map `'A' -> 1` ... `'Z' -> 26`:

```
charToInt :: Char -> Int
charToInt = (+1) . (subtract (fromEnum 'A') . fromEnum)
```

And the whole thing can be condensed to a one-liner using function composition and eta-reduction:

```
checkIfTrue = (==) . sum . map (subtract (fromEnum 'A') . fromEnum)
```

Comment: how do I specify A = 1, B = 2, C = 3?

Comment: @JayRowen, Pattern matching on the individual characters (like in Adam Smith's answer) is one to to solve it. Another is using the code snippet that karakfa wrote in a comment above.

Comment: @JayRowen You can look at my updated answer now as well.